# Seaside on Pharo - Why the weird jQuery integration syntax compared to Scriptaculous?

Tags: seaside

Example 1:

```
html scriptaculous sortable onUpdate: (html scriptaculous... etc).

html jQuery **new** sortable onStop: (html jQuery... etc).
```

Example 2:

```
html scriptaculous effect id: helpId; toggleAppear.

(html jQuery id: helpId) slideToggle: 1 seconds.
```

The way jQuery and Scriptaculous were integrated *seems* similar. Can anyone explain what design change took place between the two and its effect on syntax (especially in the second example)?

Comment: Is this only necessary on Pharo or a general Seaside thing?

Comment: It's a general seaside thing I think, I've only tested it on Pharo but I was struck by the fact it seems to work differently. If you do a 'html jQuery' it returns a jQuery class and only after id: helpId does it become an instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JQuery** has a very uniform calling pattern, and so does the integration into Seaside:

1. Query: Find the desired DOM elements.
2. Action: Perform actions on the matching elements.

Having the possibility to perform actions on multiple elements at once is very powerful and one of the benefits of JQuery. For more details and examples, have a look at [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/esug/jquery-in-seaside).

On the other hand, **script.aculo.us** is a collection of UI tools that are less generic and less uniformly organized. Most script.aculo.us calls require a single DOM ID to identify the element to work on. This is may be simpler initially, but is also less powerful.

Comment: I see. Looking at Figure 145: jQuery Lifecycle in Smalltalk on http://book.seaside.st/book/web-20/jquery/basics I can see what you mean, that image is quite informative if one knows how to read it.